# why diskConfig.cachePathBlock should be reset to nil here?

Tags: swift, kingfisher

I'm watching the source code of `Kingfisher`. And i have an question in the following code ([Source code](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/blob/master/Sources/Cache/ImageCache.swift)):

why reset `diskConfig.cachePathBlock` to `nil` at the end of init method?
I can't figure it out.

```
public convenience init(
        name: String,
        cacheDirectoryURL: URL?,
        diskCachePathClosure: DiskCachePathClosure? = nil) throws
    {
        if name.isEmpty {
            fatalError("[Kingfisher] You should specify a name for the cache. A cache with empty name is not permitted.")
        }

        let totalMemory = ProcessInfo.processInfo.physicalMemory
        let costLimit = totalMemory / 4
        let memoryStorage = MemoryStorage.Backend<Image>(config:
            .init(totalCostLimit: (costLimit > Int.max) ? Int.max : Int(costLimit)))

        var diskConfig = DiskStorage.Config(
            name: name,
            sizeLimit: 0,
            directory: cacheDirectoryURL
        )
        if let closure = diskCachePathClosure {
            diskConfig.cachePathBlock = closure
        }
        let diskStorage = try DiskStorage.Backend<Data>(config: diskConfig)
        diskConfig.cachePathBlock = nil

        self.init(memoryStorage: memoryStorage, diskStorage: diskStorage)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not setting the property to nil would keep a strong reference to the passed-in closure and potentially create a memory leak. Setting it to nil avoids this.

Assuming the nil assignment were not present, here's an example for a leak:

```
class CacheBuilder {
    func createCache() -> ImageCache {
        let cache = try! ImageCache(name: "Cache", cacheDirectoryURL: nil, diskCachePathClosure: self.path)
        return cache
    }

    func path(_ url: URL, _ str: String) -> URL {
        return url
    }

    deinit {
        print("deinit") // is not called when Cache.init is done
    }
}

class Cache {
    let cache: ImageCache

    init() {
        let builder = CacheBuilder()
        self.cache = builder.createCache()
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah. i know this code is used to release reference here. But, from my point of view,  `diskConfig` is a local variable, it'll be destroyed after function call.  And i can't find any reference cycle here. So i just confused how does this code cause a memory leak?

Comment: Look at the initialization sequence: `diskConfig` is stored in `diskStorage`, which in turn is stored in the `ImageCache` instance that's just created. Depending on how and where the closure is defined, this may lead to a leak, even though it's not a cycle.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. Now, i know the reference chain: `diskCachePathClosure ` -> `diskConfig` -> `diskStorage` -> `ImageCache instance`.  Can you show me a leak example? I can't  imagine that situation.

Comment: I write some examples, but there's no leak occur. So i'll very appreciate it if you can give me a leak demo.

Comment: Updated my answer with an example

Comment: I test your code with `Kingfisher` demo. And even thought `diskConfig.cachePathBlock = nil` is removed, the `deinit` still didn't execute. So there's no different with or without `diskConfig.cachePathBlock = nil`. And `deinit` will alwarys execute when `Cache` instance is destroyed.

Comment: In my opinion, `diskConfig.cachePathBlock = nil` has no affect since `diskStorage` holder the reference of that block too.